# The difference between Vanilla and stacked LSTM

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am doing on the research of the different structures of LSTM networks. I can not exactly understand the difference between Vanilla and Stacked LSTM. As I understand from some articles there is no hidden layer in Vanilla LSTM. So It means we have just input and output layers. And In the Stacked LSTM, It can be at least one hidden layer and we can increase the size of the hidden layer. Are these assumptions are true? Do I have the right understanding? Thanks from beforehand

Comment: where do these phrases come from? vanilla and stacked? any links?

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/ there is this link. But he has no references to his implementations.

Comment: he has code that specifices what he does with each one of them. in that article atleast, vanilla is 1 hidden layer, stacked is more than 1.

Comment: This might be useful @GunayAbdullayeva. It has detailed information about Stacking in LSTM's , as well as hidden representations In Vanilla LSTM.

Comment: Yes, in that article It says vanilla is 1 hidden layer, stacked is more than 1 but I can not find more information on the internet which might be the strong reference